# libcaffe error in cpp eclipse

Tags: caffe, leveldb

I just want to use cpp to read LevelDB features extracted from caffe.
I use the following code in eclipse:

```
// Copyright 2014 BVLC and contributors.

#include <glog/logging.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // for snprintf
#include <google/protobuf/text_format.h>
#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <leveldb/write_batch.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

//#include "cpp/sample.pb.h"
#include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"  // for: Datum
using namespace caffe;
#define NUMBER_FEATURES_PER_IMAGE 16
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Not enough arguments!\nusage: %s <feature_folder>", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

LOG(INFO) << "Creating leveldb object\n";
leveldb::DB* db;
leveldb::Options options;
options.create_if_missing = true;
leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, argv[1], &db);
assert(status.ok());

leveldb::Iterator* it = db->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions());
int i = 0;
double count = 0.0f;
for (it->SeekToFirst(); it->Valid(); it->Next())
{
    Datum d;
    d.clear_float_data();
    d.clear_data();
    d.ParseFromString(it->value().ToString());
    for (int j = 0; j < d.height(); ++j)
        count += d.float_data(j);
    i++;
}
assert(it->status().ok());

LOG(INFO) << "Number of datums (or feature vectors): " << i << "\n";;
LOG(INFO) << "Reduction of All Vectors to A Scalar Value: " << count << "\n";
delete it;
}
```

It builds without error,but when running it says:
/home/deep/cuda-workspace/ReadLevelDB/Debug/ReadLevelDB: error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

what is the problem ?

Comment: my temporary workaround is to copy libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3 to whatever directory i'm working from.

Answer (score 0):

You program fail to find *.so. There are three method:

1. Create links of *.so in /usr/lib:

> ln -s /where/you/install/lib/*.so /usr/lib
>
> sudo ldconfig

2. Modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/where/you/install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> sudo ldconfig

3. Modify /etc/ld.so.conf:

> vim /etc/ld.so.conf

add /where/you/install/lib

> sudo ldconfig

Comment: I have added the path to all caffe .so files , in this 3 methods..still getting same error in eclipse . error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: